# Collection from CollectionEditor could not be converted to item

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created Custom collection and custom collection editor for editing the collection in designer level for windows form application.

But when I click on the Add button of collection editor the value is retrieved as Collection itself instead of Item.

Below is my code part:

```
public MyItem 
{
 .....
}

[EditorAttribute(typeof(MyItemCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyItemCollectionConverter))]
public MyItemCollection : : ICollection, IDisposable, ICloneable, IList, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{

     //implemented all the interfaces.

     int IList.Add(object value)
     {
         Add((MyItem)value);  //Exception thrown as "could not convert type of MyItemCollection to MyItem"

         //Why itemcollection coming as value instead of item.
     }

}



public class MyItemCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCollectionEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override Type CreateCollectionItemType()
    {
        return typeof(MyItemCollection);
    }

    protected override bool CanSelectMultipleInstances()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}


public class MyItemCollectionConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)value).GetProperties(attributes);
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return context == null || context.PropertyDescriptor == null
        || (context.Instance != null && GetCount(context.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(context.Instance)) > 0);
    }

    public override /*TypeConverter*/ bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }
    }

    int GetCount(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)value).GetProperties(null).Count;
    }

    public override /*TypeConverter*/ object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            int count = GetCount(value);
            return count > 0 ? String.Format("Count = {0}", count) : string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    } 
}
```

Could anyone please let me know, why the item collection is came for adding instead of item?

Comment: my guess would be that you pass the collection to Add(...) in stead of the item.

Comment: How would i pass the collection? I have done only clicking on Add button in collection editor.

Comment: I don't know. `Add((MyItem)value)` --> value obviously is of the wrong type. It's a collection in stead of an item. How? I don't know. Do some debugging in the converter and you might find out I guess.

Comment: By the way, it is not forbidden to use your own brains and to put some effort in your own work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error could be the implementation of this method:

```
protected override Type CreateCollectionItemType()
{
    return typeof(MyItemCollection);
}
```

This should possibly be

```
protected override Type CreateCollectionItemType()
{
    return typeof(MyItem);
}
```

See [documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.createcollectionitemtype(v=vs.110).aspx)